# Research Scientist vs Staff Scientist in US academia

Tags: united-states, job

I am wondering what is the difference between a Research Scientist and a Staff Scientist in the US academia. Are these positions like a senior postdoc?

Answer (score 8):

They could be anything and it will vary widely between institution. They may or may not be "academic" positions. They may or may not be "senior" positions. They may or may not involve advising/mentoring students, especially graduate students. They may or may not be open to tenure. A given institution might use either of the terms for something essentially the same as the other at a different institution.

If an institution uses both terms, you will have to ask them about the difference.

Of all the above only "tenurable" is unlikely, though a long term contract or an open ended contract is probably available. That would make it unlike a postdoc position.

Comment: Can you give an example of a research scientist or staff scientist position that was tenure track in the last ten years?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, no, but I can't rule it out either. I can imagine an eminent scientist, hired only for research as a special case. Not exactly faculty, but worth keeping if possible. But it would be rare, I think.